# Python processes fail to start

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

I'm running the following code block in my application. While running it with python3.4 I get 'python quit unexpectedly' popup on my screen. The data missing from the aOut file is for a bunch of iterations and it is in chunks.  Say 0-1000 items in the list are not present and others have the data. The other items run properly on their own without intervention.

While using python2.7 the failures are for items ~3400-4400 in the list.

On logging I see that, the detect() call are not made for processes from 0-1000 (i.e) process.start() calls dont trigger the detect method.

I am doing this on MAC OS Sierra. What is happening here? Is there a better way to achieve my purpose?

```
def detectInBatch (aList, aOut):
    #iterate through the objects
    processPool = []
    pthreadIndex = 0
    pIndex = 0
    manager = Manager()
    dict = manager.dict()
    outline = ""
    print("Threads: ", getMaxThreads()) # max threads is 20

    for key in aList:
        print("Key: %s, pIndex: %d"%(key.key, pIndex))
        processPool.append(Process(target=detect, args=(key.key, dict)))
        pthreadIndex = pthreadIndex + 1
        pIndex = pIndex + 1
        #print("Added for %d" %(pIndex))

        if(pthreadIndex == getMaxThreads()):
            print("ProcessPool size: %d" %len(processPool))
            for process in processPool:
                #print("Started")
                process.start()
            #end for
            print("20 Processes started")

            for process in processPool:
                #print("Joined")
                process.join()
            #end for
            print("20 Processes joined")

            for key in dict.keys():
                outline = outline + dict.get(key)
            #end for

            dict.clear()
            pthreadIndex = 0
            processPool = []
        #endif
    #endfor

    if(pthreadIndex != 0):
        for process in processPool:
#             print("End Start")
            process.start()
        #end for

        for process in processPool:
#             print("End done")
            process.join()
        #end for

        for key in dict.keys():
            print ("Dict: " + dict.get(key))
            outline = outline + dict.get(key)
        #end for
    #endif

    aOut.write(outline)
#end method detectInBatch
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the 'unexpected quit' perhaps try to ignore the exception with

```
try:
    your_loop()
except:
    pass
```

Then, put in some logging to track the root cause.